# How to catch GenServer.call(destination, ...) failure when destination process doesn't exist

Tags: elixir

In my application all logged users are represented by a `GenServer`, I call a `UserAgent`, which basically keeps in memory the state of each user. All those processes are registered across the cluster in a distributed registry based on [Horde](https://hexdocs.pm/horde/readme.html) with a unique ID. Whenever the user does some action, the client application sends the action to be performed along with the `user_id`. On server side, the controller checks the parameters (mandatory, optional, syntax, etc) and eventually calls `UserAgent.the_action(user_id, other_params)`. The `the_action(...)` function simply sends a message to the server with the action to be performed: `GenServer.call(via_tuple(id), {:the_action, params})`.

In some cases, the `UserAgent` referenced by `user_id` doesn't exist any more, for example because the user had been inactive for some time and the process had been cleaned out (the sesion had expired) or because parts of the cluster are not reachable at that moment (imaginary use case for the moment). In those situations the call `GenServer.call(via_tuple(id), {:the_action, params})` results in the error below which also crashes the HTTP endpoint process (`#PID<0.1359.0>` below) which in turn results in a `500` HTTP error (the `dump` api call, well, dumps the state of a process for debug purposes):

```
[error] #PID<0.1359.0> running AppWeb.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.1358.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4001 (http)
Request: GET /api/v1/dump/5f534b99d6ca3fe1ff6d2f78
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call({:via, Horde.Registry, {App.DReg, "5f534b99d6ca3fe1ff6d2f78"}}, :dump, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated \
        with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
```

I just can't figure out how to intercept this error. I actually ended up with calling `Horde.Registry.lookup(App.UserAgent.via_tuple(user_id))` in the client part of the `UserAgent` and then calling `GenServer.call()  with the returned` pid` or returning an error to the controller if the process was not found.

I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `GenServer.call/3` [handles errors](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.4/lib/elixir/lib/gen_server.ex#L1000-L1028) in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). It nevertheless calls `whereis/1`, so you might either call `whereis/1` yourself or replicate logic from the code I linked or use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#try/1) to `catch` the exception.